# Right-CTRL key not supported in Kubuntu 14.04?

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu

In my fresh install of Kubuntu 14.04, I can't use anymore the (pretty useful) shortcut to move along words: <kbd>(right) CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Left (or Right) Arrow</kbd>.

The Left-Control key is working fine. If I try to add a secondary shortcut for this action in System settings > shortcuts & gestures > standard shortcuts > forward one word, I got an error popup saying:

```
This key is not supported by Qt
```

My keyboard didn't change, it's a basic French AZERTY 101 keys. Is there a trick to configure something somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Unity on Ubuntu 14.04, I managed to have a fully working right control key using keyboard "Français" instead of "Français (variante)", using the keyboard icon on top right of the screen.

"Français (variante)" is the default selected during installation...

I don't know how to apply that on Kubuntu, sorry !

Comment: It works for Kubuntu as well, thanks! The only thing is that in Kubuntu you have to choose `Défaut` instead `Français (variante)`.

Comment: I don't think this is a solution, it's just a workaround. "Français (variante)" is much better for many reasons (AltGr characters are more useful, for example there is an easy access to 'œ'). I would rather choose @Neptilo answer...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04, using the "French (alternative)" layout (which probably stands for "Français (variante)". The issue seems to originate from a bug in xkb.

I could solve it **without changing the layout** and **without remapping keys**.

Follow these steps:

- Open `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/fr` as administrator.
- Find the line `include "level5(rctrl_switch)"` and remove it or comment it out. (Commenting out is done by adding `//` at the beginning of the line.)
- Save the changes
- Delete all the `.xkm` files in `/var/lib/xkb` (or move them to another folder). This will force to rebuild xkb.
- Reboot.

[This blog post](http://linuxfr.org/users/rewind/journaux/perte-de-ctrl) (in French), addresses the problem and points to [this bug entry](https://bugs.mageia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11515) which helped me figure out the solution.

I hope it will help a lot of French *ubuntu users.

Comment: Neptilo method is the best, because in french oelig and OElig are not exotic characters (œ Œ), and Français (variante) is the only one that has these with AltGr[+Shift]+o. Bien vu, bon œil ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem. My right Ctrl key stopped working after upgrading to Kubuntu 14.04. I resolved it by doing the following:

Checking the current mapping of the keys. In a terminal type:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep 37
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
```

This is the current binding of your left ctrl key. Now check the right key:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep 105
keycode 105 = ISO_Level5_Shift NoSymbol ISO_Level5_Shift
```

I had this strange ouput, clearly the right key was not binded to anything. To fix this I configured a custom .Xmodmap file:

```
$ echo -e 'clear control\nkeycode 105 = Control_R\nadd control = Control_R Control_L' > ~/.Xmodmap
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap # apply the configuration
```

Hope it helps you too!

Answer (score -1):

Try 
`ctrl-alt-shift (left/right)arrow`

http://www.unixmen.com/quick-tip-enable-workspaces-ubuntu-14-04-lts-desktop/